# How would you randomize a wave texture per brick on a brick texture?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I followed this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoQgq7n9Rwk) but have realized there's 1 problem.

The wave textures in the video almost look like they're connecting even though it's seperated by black lines.

My .blend file should not be needed since the material from the video and mine are the same colorwise.

Comment: Hi. You could offset the UVs at the beginning of the node tree to achieve this.

At 7:00 in the tutorial he adds a white noise that ends up generating a random color per plank. Just duplicate this part of the node tree, and add the result to the UVs on X, Y, or both.

Comment: @holybobine thanks.